# How to load my rails console with spanish

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have set up a my application with spanish and english. On my console i am getting error messages in english if object is returning validation error. I want to set my rails console so i will get validation error message in spanish.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work:

```
I18n.locale = 'es'
```

Comment: Getting this error.

C:\projects\CyncErp>ruby script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.8)
>> I18.locale = 'es'
NameError: uninitialized constant I18
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_suppo
rt/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_suppo
rt/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_suppo
rt/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
        from (irb):1

Comment: You've missed the `n` off `I18n`

Comment: @Shadwell Now it's not returning error but still validation messages are coming in english.

Comment: Hmmm, okay, works for me I'm afraid so might not be able to help. For example `User.create!` after `I18n.locale = 'es'` gives me a load of missing translation messages like : `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password confirmation translation missing: es, activerecord, errors, models, user, attributes, password_confirmation, blank`

Comment: Just wondering: you have got spanish translations in your application, right? They won't magically appear unless you've provided them. There are a load of sample rails translations here: http://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale

Comment: @Shadwell Thanks. i missed some configuration.